# Can a primary key be a separate entity

Tags: database, database-design, primary-key

I'm making an E/R diagram for a database about doctors and prescribing drugs.

At one point it says that a **drug's trade name and formula is recorded and that a drug is identified by its trade name**.

It also says that the **trade name is identified only among the products of the pharmaceutical company that supplies the drugs**.

So I assume that the trade name would have to be a separate entity and a relationship between the trade name, the drug, and the company would need to be recorded but if that's the case then how would I create a table for drugs if the primary key is its own entity?

Comment: try using composite constraints. you could actually make unique key based on 2 columns. if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: and having an example or a dummy table would help people answer better..

Comment: Well I haven't created the table yet but for my E/R diagram, I set it up like a 3 way relationship with one relationship in the center and the drug, company, and trade name are the 3 entities (with all being one to many relationships).

Comment: **a table for drugs if the primary key is its own entity** can you elaborate this...

Comment: It sounds to me like drug is supposed to be a weak entity identified by the pharmaceutical company's identifier and the drug's trade name.

Comment: Seems to me like the drug's trade name should be the primary key of the drugs table, that's also should be connected to the pharmaceutical companies table in a M:1 (multiple drugs per company) relationship. I don't see a reason for making a new table just to keep the trade name.